# Loading images into html5 canvas

Tags: javascript, node.js, image, html5-canvas, sails.js

I am using nodejs sails for my app. 
The app is going to use 50-100 images at some points.
I was wondering if someone can point pro and cons of using /assests/images/ folder vs outside repository i.e. AWS S3 for image storing and pulling to draw on the canvas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, use a CDN if you have the option.

**Pros**:
- Save enormously on website load time / speed.
- Better for organization / maintenance.

**Cons**:
- One more paid account; but you may end up having to upgrade your hosting anyway if your images continue to add up with more.

►*But a large factor is still, what your plans are for the future of this web property, will you be adding more images, will the website and other parts of it grow? What is your current hosting? Will you need to update the images alot? Do you have one developer on this or several? Are these large HQ heavy images? Or this just a one off landing page that will never be touched again?*

But I do agree with the other answer, if you'll only have max 100 images; then a CDN is more of luxury. But IMO it's never a fixed amount, and it sounds like you may have several of these HTML5 canvas pages.

Comment: number of images will stay constant. the app is a board game. and images are game pieces, fields, etc. Will AWS S3 be faster then /assets/images for website loading?

Comment: hmm.. if you have nothing else on that server aside from this small web app; it wouldn't be that much faster. But if you begin to have ALOT of traffic, a CDN would be a better idea. Maybe initially keep the images on the same server, see if you have any problems. If you start to get a lot of traffic, or end up having to put alot more weight on the same server switch to a CDN.

Answer (score 2):

I would use /assets/images folder if you know that the images are fixed to 50-100.

- that is, they will not change
- 50-100 images is not alot of images

If the images are dynamic and changing all the time, then I would use aws s3.  To load 50-100 images from S3 will create a "buffering" effect, but it shouldn't be too intolerable.

Comment: thanks. I'm trying to run locally using /images folder and it seems there is "buffering" effect anyway. I was hoping image load to be almost instantaneous but that's not the case. Therefore I was not sure if using /image folder is a proper way.